# Boolean method to determine consecutive numbers

Tags: java, boolean

Write a method named consecutive that accepts three integers as parameters and returns true if they are three consecutive numbers; that is, if the numbers can be arranged into an order such that there is some integer k such that the parameters' values are k, k+1, and k+2. Your method should return false if the integers are not consecutive. Note that order is not significant; your method should return the same result for the same three integers passed in any order. 
For example, the calls consecutive(1, 2, 3), consecutive(3, 2, 4), and consecutive(-10, -8, -9) would return true. The calls consecutive(3, 5, 7), consecutive(1, 2, 2), and consecutive(7, 7, 9) would return false.

This is what I have so far and keep getting infinite loop error and skipped tests

```
public boolean consecutive(int x, int y, int z) {
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
x = kb.nextInt();
y = kb.nextInt();
z = kb.nextInt();
if (((x < y && x < z) && (y < z && ((y - x) == 1) && ((z - x) == 2))) 
   ||((z < y && ((z - x) == 1) && ((y - x) == 2)))) 
{
    return true;
} else if (((y < x && y < z)&& (x < z && ((x - y) == 1) && ((z - y) == 2))) 
   || ((z < x && ((z - y) == 1) && ((x - y) == 2))))
{
        return true;
} else if (((z < x && z < y)&& (y < x && ((y - z) == 1) && ((x - z) == 2))) 
   ||((x < y && ((x - z) == 1) && ((y - z) == 2))))
{
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh my eyes :( :-/

Comment: Infinite loop ? without loops or recursive call... I will not comment on that algo

Comment: Ok let talk about that code ... why did you receive `x,y,z` in parameters, what are the vlaue ? You never close a Scanner, that's bad. And for the logic, you should try some math instead of PURE condition or simply find the smaller and bigger number ...

Comment: There's no more red rag to a bull than the *totally* unnecessary `if ... then return else` construct :-) Ditch the `else` lines since, whether you've returned if the `if` part or carried on, they have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is *serious* overkill and pretty much unreadable to anyone who hasn't spent a large proportion of their career in C :-)

You should *always* strive for readability (and hence maintainability) first, reverting to less readable code only when absolutely necessary. Even if you do revert, you should then document why and what you've done so the next poor soul that has to maintain your code won't be cursing your name.

For this specific case, what you are attempting can be achieved in much simpler code such as the following (pseudo-code):

```
def areConsecutive(a, b, c):
    if a > b: swap a, b
    if b > c: swap b, c
    if a > b: swap a, b
    return (b - a == 1) and (c - b == 1)
```

The three `if` statements are simply an unrolled bubble sort to ensure `a`, `b` and `c` are in ascending order, then you simply check to ensure the difference between them is one in both cases.

There's no need to put them into a list or array to sort them since sorting three items is relatively easy (the swap can be done with `int t = a; a = b; b = t;`).

In terms of Java code (once you've moved the input to *outside* the function where it belongs), you'd end up with something like:

```
bool areConsecutive(int a, int b, int c) {
    int t;
    if (a > b) { t = a; a = b; b = t; }
    if (b > c) { t = b; b = c; c = t; }
    if (a > b) { t = a; a = b; b = t; }
    return (b - a = 1) && (c - b == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The consecutive method is passed with three values , then why you are reading from the console.

> create an array with the size of 3 elements.
>
> Sort the arrays using `Arrays.Sort` method
>
> Check the difference between the second and the first number is 1 and difference between Third and the second number is 1.

Code :

```
public boolean consecutive(int x, int y, int z) {
int [] numbers = new int [3];
numbers[0] = x;
numbers[1] = y;
numbers[2] = z;
Arrays.sort(numbers);
boolean isConsecutive = (numbers[1]==numbers[0]+1)&&(numbers[2]==numbers[1]+1);
return isConsecutive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing value why using scanner?
Remove those lines and its working. You can use another logic to determine consecutive numbers.

```
public boolean consecutive(int x, int y, int z) {
     if (((x < y && x < z) && (y < z && ((y - x) == 1) && ((z - x) == 2))) ||((z < y && ((z - x) == 1) && ((y - x) == 2)))) {
        return true;
     } else if (((y < x && y < z)&& (x < z && ((x - y) == 1) && ((z - y) == 2))) ||
                                ((z < x && ((z - y) == 1) && ((x - y) == 2)))){
        return true;
     } else if (((z < x && z < y)&& (y < x && ((y - z) == 1) && ((x - z) == 2))) ||((x < y && ((x - z) == 1) && ((y - z) == 2)))){
        return true;
     } else
       return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove these code:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
x = kb.nextInt();
y = kb.nextInt();
z = kb.nextInt();
```

Or use Like this:

```
public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        x = kb.nextInt();
        y = kb.nextInt();
        z = kb.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Result:" + consecutive(x, y, z));

    }

    public static boolean consecutive(int x, int y, int z) {
        if (((x < y && x < z) && (y < z && ((y - x) == 1) && ((z - x) == 2))) || ((z < y && ((z - x) == 1) && ((y - x) == 2)))) {
            return true;
        } else if (((y < x && y < z) && (x < z && ((x - y) == 1) && ((z - y) == 2)))
                || ((z < x && ((z - y) == 1) && ((x - y) == 2)))) {
            return true;
        } else if (((z < x && z < y) && (y < x && ((y - z) == 1) && ((x - z) == 2))) || ((x < y && ((x - z) == 1) && ((y - z) == 2)))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a list with the numbers, sort it and do de diference between the elements:

```
public static boolean myConsecutive(int x, int y, int z) {
        final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(x);
        list.add(y);
        list.add(z);

        Collections.sort(list);
        return (list.get(2) - list.get(1) == 1 && list.get(1) - list.get(0) == 1);
}
```